# Multithreading problem with TestScheduler

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, system.reactive

I'am working with Microsoft.Reactive.Testing (4.1.5), and I have some problems when using Buffer method. My unit test stops in assert error, but buffer function continue to work in another thread after this exception.

How to manage this multithread problem ?

This a dotnet core 2.2 application. All unit tests are ok except when I am using Buffer method.

```cs
var newObservable = observable
    .SelectMany(msg => msg.ObjectList)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));

var scheduler = new TestScheduler(); 
var source = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(records);   
var testObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<IList<MyObject>>();

newObservable.Subscribe(testObserver);

scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks);
testObserver.Messages
            .Should().HaveCount(1);
```

Comment: `Buffer` has a `IScheduler` parameter. Put your `TestScheduler` there.

Comment: With scheduler in parameter, I have the same behavior

Comment: The code `observable.SelectMany(msg => msg.ObjectList).Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150))` does nothing. You're not saving a reference or calling `Subscribe` so it's just hanging around doing nothing. Is this your real code?

Comment: I modified the code to return a new variable. Sorry, it was not a real code.